# why references in adapter constructor are not updated?

Tags: android

Consider folowing code:

```
public class MediaItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    final List<Row> rows;
    public MediaItemAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        Log.d("mediaadapter", "listcreation: " + data.size());
        rows = new ArrayList<Row>();// member variable
        int i=0;
        for (HashMap<String, String> addvert:data) {

            rows.add(new MeadiaRow((LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), addvert));
            Log.d("mediaadapter", addvert.get("title"));
            if (i % 20 == 0) {
                rows.add(new SourseRow((LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)));
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

It is constructor of my adapter. After each 20 MediaRows, I wish to add one sourse row. It has ArrayList `data`. The problem that data is always empty.  I build my adapter according to this [tutorial](http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/). In a tutorial thingth works fine. But in tutorial initial dataset is predefined. In my cade initial data set is empty and populates in working time. However, after I call `notifyDataSetChanged` the `data` remains empty (even though the dataset is not).
How can I get updated values for data?

Comment: Check this solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is nesessary to do - is to move

```
int i=0;
        for (HashMap<String, String> addvert:data) {

            rows.add(new MeadiaRow((LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), addvert));
            Log.d("mediaadapter", addvert.get("title"));
            if (i % 20 == 0) {
                rows.add(new SourseRow((LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)));
            }
            i++;
        }
```

from adapter to overriden notifyDataSetChanged in adapter class